# Pandas subtract a date incrementally until a condition is met on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, timedelta

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name         Date
Person A     2019-06-18
Person A     2019-05-14
Person A     2019-04-03
Person B     2019-05-19
Person C     2019-05-16
Person C     2019-05-23
Person C     2019-05-15
Person D     2019-06-21
```

What I want to do is modify the dates of anyone who is between 5/14 and 6/14 and subtract 7 days. If, after this operation is complete, they are still in that range, subtract another 7 days.

In the end, I want the data to look like this:

```
Name         Date
Person A     2019-06-18
Person A     2019-05-07
Person A     2019-04-03
Person B     2019-05-12
Person C     2019-05-09
Person C     2019-05-09
Person C     2019-05-08
Person D     2019-06-21
```

(After this step, I'll roll it up so that each person has one row with all of their dates, then send them their info--but I think I can figure that out on my own.)

Right now, I have the following code "working":

```
df = df[(df['Date'] >= '2019-05-14') & (df['Date'] <= '2019-06-14')]
df['Date'] = df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=7)
```

However, I don't know how to loop it, and I also don't know how to apply this without losing my original data.

Because of this, my code produces this frame:

```
Name         Date
Person A     2019-05-07
Person B     2019-05-12
Person C     2019-05-16
Person C     2019-05-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `Date` column is of `datetime64` type.

The initial step is to define "border dates":

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-05-14')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-14')
```

Then we have to define the function to be applied to each date:

```
def fn(dat):
    inRng = (dat >= start_date) & (dat <= end_date)
    dat2 = dat
    if inRng:
        diffWeeks = int((dat - start_date) / np.timedelta64(1, 'W')) + 1
        dat2 -= np.timedelta64(diffWeeks, 'W')
    return dat2
```

And the last step is to apply this function.
To ease comparison of source data and results, I decided to substitute
the result in a new column (`Dat2`):

```
df['Dat2'] = df.Date.apply(fn)
```

When you print your DataFrame, you will get:

```
       Name       Date       Dat2
0  Person A 2019-06-18 2019-06-18
1  Person A 2019-05-14 2019-05-07
2  Person A 2019-04-03 2019-04-03
3  Person B 2019-05-19 2019-05-12
4  Person C 2019-05-16 2019-05-09
5  Person C 2019-05-23 2019-05-09
6  Person C 2019-05-15 2019-05-08
7  Person D 2019-06-21 2019-06-21
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just calculate how many times you have to subtract from each date, and do it in one step

---

```
m = df.Date.between('2019-05-14', '2019-06-14')
u = df[m]

d = u.Date - pd.Timestamp('2019-05-13')
o = np.ceil(d.dt.days / 7)

df.loc[m, 'Date'] = df.loc[m, 'Date'] - (o * np.timedelta64(7, 'D'))
```

```
       Name       Date
0  Person A 2019-06-18
1  Person A 2019-05-07
2  Person A 2019-04-03
3  Person B 2019-05-12
4  Person C 2019-05-09
5  Person C 2019-05-09
6  Person C 2019-05-08
7  Person D 2019-06-21
```

---

Here is a version that doesn't modify the frame in-place:

```
m = df.Date.between('2019-05-14', '2019-06-14')
d = df.Date - pd.Timestamp('2019-05-13')

o = np.ceil(d.dt.days / 7)

df.assign(Date=np.where(m, df.Date - (o * np.timedelta64(7, 'D')), df.Date))
```

```
       Name       Date
0  Person A 2019-06-18
1  Person A 2019-05-07
2  Person A 2019-04-03
3  Person B 2019-05-12
4  Person C 2019-05-09
5  Person C 2019-05-09
6  Person C 2019-05-08
7  Person D 2019-06-21
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make a simple loop with `range()` and after that use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally change each row if its between the two dates:

```
for i in range(2):
    df['Date'] = np.where(df['Date'].between('20190514','20190614'), 
                          df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=7), 
                          df['Date'])

print(df)

       Name       Date
0  Person A 2019-06-18
1  Person A 2019-05-07
2  Person A 2019-04-03
3  Person B 2019-05-12
4  Person C 2019-05-09
5  Person C 2019-05-09
6  Person C 2019-05-08
7  Person D 2019-06-21
```

Comment: your method with a range of 2 works with the data given, but if the date is e.g. `20190613 ` it won't, you need at least a range of 4 or 5 I think as the interval of date you look between is one month

Comment: Op specifically says to substract twice. Thats why I used range. But we can add 5 just to be sure..

Comment: I see, I understand that OP wants no date between these two bounds and the operation should be done until then. Just an interpretation of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a function and then applying it to the date column. The `pd.Series.apply` method works by passing each value to the function provided. Inside the function you have a simple while loop that keeps subtracting 7 days until you are within the date range you wish.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def date_modifier(x):
    d = x
    while True:
        if d >= dt(2019, 5, 14) and d<=dt(2019, 6, 14):
            d-= timedelta(days=7)
        else:
            return d
df['Date-Mod'] = df['Date'].apply(date_modifier)
```

Gives the following output:

```
      Name       Date   Date-Mod
0  PersonA 2019-06-18 2019-06-18
1  PersonA 2019-05-14 2019-05-07
2  PersonA 2019-04-03 2019-04-03
3  PersonB 2019-05-19 2019-05-12
4  PersonC 2019-05-16 2019-05-09
5  PersonC 2019-05-23 2019-05-09
6  PersonC 2019-05-15 2019-05-08
7  PersonD 2019-06-21 2019-06-21
```